# Action return view in different model with parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have a view that has all my projects and I want only the superAdmin to be able to editProjects I am calling editProjects action in my SuperAdmin controller but I want to have the editProjects view under projects. How can I get my specific project for my view. Here is my code

View Projects view

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectId)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectName)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectCode)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NatureOfIndustry)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditProject", "SuperAdmin", new { id = item.ProjectId }) |
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ProjectId })
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody> //Super admin action                                 public ActionResult EditProject(int id)
        {
            if (id < 0)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var project = context.Projects.Where(p =>
                p.ProjectId.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (project == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View("~/Views/Projects/EditProject.cshtml",new ProjectUpdateModel()
            {
                ProjectId = project.ProjectId,
                ProjectName = project.ProjectName,
                ProjectCode = project.ProjectCode,
                NatureOfIndustry = project.NatureOfIndustry
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out
I was missing "NULL" in actionlink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditProject", "SuperAdmin", new { id = item.ProjectId }, null) |
```

Now it works